# How do I create a new workbook from selected data and name that workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to create a new excel workbook and it works great but I would like to name it "FireDrill Report" but I don't know how to code it to give it the name. Can someone help me with this?

```
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the new workbook in a variable and then save it to give it its name, something like this ...

```
Dim objWB As Workbook
Set objWB = Application.Workbooks.Add
... do stuff
objWB.Save(with your parameters)
```

... saving it names it.